# Unable to get Ajax POST working with Emberjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ember.js

What I am trying to do now is trying to send data to the database via Ajax POST. I will first start with the HTML form I have,

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="project">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="projectname">Project Name: </label>

                    <div class="controls">
                        {{!view App.TextFieldEmpty}}
                        <input type="text" id="projectname" required title="First Name is Required!" pattern="[A-z ]{10,}" placeholder="Enter Project Name"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="projectdesc">Project Description:</label>

                    <div class="controls">
                        <textarea rows="3" id="projectdesc" placeholder="Enter Project Desc"
                                  required="Description Required"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <button class="btn" {{action 'createNew'}}>Add Project</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Next, is my `App.js`, According to Ember guidelines, we have to map templates first right? So here it is my `router`:

```
App.Router.map(function() {

    this.resource('project');

});
```

Next, the table I am inserting the data into is a simple one, having just three fields; `id, projectname & projectdesc`.

```
App.Model = Ember.Object.extend({

});

App.Project = App.Model.extend({
    id : null,
    projectname : null,
    projectdesc : null
});
```

Now about the issue,

```
App.ProjectController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions : {
        createNew : function() {
            this.get('model').createNew();
        }
    }
});
    App.ProjectRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    });


    App.Project.reopenClass({
        createNew : function() {

            dataString = $("#project").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "http://ankur.local/users/createNewProject",
                data : dataString,
                dataType : "json",
                success : function(data) {
                    alert("yes");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I am getting this error on the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'createNew'
```

That appears to be on the line

```
this.get('model').createNew();
```

Furthermore, I am using non-RESTful PHP backend.

Even though I think I have created the method in the model. Moroever, I have used the GET exactly this way and it worked but the difference was I returned the method in the model. In this case, I thought I had to call the method from the controller. Where I might be doing wrong? I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
this.get('model').createNew();
```

Try the below.

```
App.Project.createNew();
```

Comment: Okay, that worked! I think data is now going but there's again a small glitch. The projectname & projectdesc are going as 0 in the database why? :(

Comment: What are you getting in your php layer when you are sending project name and description and is the id of the record getting saved as "0"??