# Data going as 0 in the database while using Ajax POST

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, ember.js

This question follows from the question, [Unable to get Ajax POST working with Emberjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19107151/unable-to-get-ajax-post-working-with-emberjs/19107221?noredirect=1#comment28251743_19107221)

Even though I can see the POST request being sent on the console but the data is getting inserted into the database as 0.

Here's my backend, I am using Codeigniter.

Controller,

```
function createNewProject() {
                $this -> load -> model('usermodel');
                $projectname = $this -> input -> post('projectname');
                $projectdesc = $this -> input -> post('projectdesc');
                $this -> usermodel -> createProject($projectname, $projectdesc);
        }
```

Model:

```
function createProject($projectname, $projectdesc) {
                $this -> db -> set('projectname', $projectname);
                $this -> db -> set('projectdesc', $projectdesc);
                $q = $this -> db -> insert('projects');
                return;
        }
```

Here's updated `App.js` controller,

```
App.ProjectController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions : {
        createNew : function() {
            App.Project.createNew();
        }
    }
});

App.ProjectRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

});

App.Project.reopenClass({
    createNew : function() {

        dataString = $("#project").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "http://ankur.local/users/createNewProject",
            data : dataString,
            dataType : "json",
            success : function(data) {
                alert("yes");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

And HTML is same if you see my linked post and a weird thing, I am not even getting alert box on success. Where I might be making a mistake?

Comment: You are passing serialized json data to createNewProject. How is this data mapped to the vars you are using to create the new record?

Comment: So I have to deserialize the data on backend?

Comment: Sometimes, yes. If you are truly posting json, which is what your script says you are, you'll have to grab the json and convert it to a native datatype and then insert the values. I've never seen serialize used with json before so you may want to double check what you are sending to the script.

Comment: @ChrisRasco looks to me like the script is passing form values (assuming `#project` is a form), not JSON. See http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: @Phil `#project` is indeed a form.

Comment: @ChrisRasco, dataType defines the type of data that you're expecting back from the server, so what the OP has is fine.

Comment: @Phil - good point, but the json data type may be throwing CI off as it may be expecting json and not form data.

Comment: @JohnAltar Are you loading the right model "usermodel"? Do you have a "projectmodel"?

Comment: @ChrisRasco I think issue is with serverside.

Comment: @ChrisRasco yes, I am loading the right model, I double checked that.

Comment: @JohnAltar Just noticed, your `#project` element is **not** a form but a `<script>` tag. This would be why `serialize()` wasn't working. See my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding CodeIgniter's Input Class -
"The function returns FALSE (boolean) if the item you are attempting to retrieve does not exist."

Essentially, the problem is that you $_POST['projectname'] and $_POST['projectdesc'] are not being presented to the CI controller, so when you invoke the CI input class you get 0 back.

Comment: I tried this before but it worked now, strange, may be I was missing something.

Comment: `serialize()` is perfectly fine for POST data as it creates a valid *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* string however, I get the feeling it wasn't working correctly for the `#project` element.

Comment: So, `serialize()` is more secure?

Comment: @JohnAltar Not at all

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19107151/283366) (the one including the HTML), you haven't set any name attributes on your `<input>` elements therefore, `serialize()` isn't going to create the correct POST payload. You should also use `serialize()` on the actual form, eg

```
var dataString = $('#project form.form-horizontal').serialize();
```

You can also inspect POST payloads in your browser's networking console. You should probably check that next time.

Comment: Just set the name attributes on my `<input>` elements. But the POST payload in the networking console is empty.

Comment: @JohnAltar Time to do some JS debugging then. I'd set a breakpoint at your `dataString = $("#project").serialize();` line. I'd also make sure `$('#project')` is returning a valid DOM element